# Deleting expired sessions from mysql

Tags: mysql, perl, session

I am using perl and mysql for storing user sessions. If an user click logout, i can able to delete the session. But if the session expires, it fills the database like zombies. So i have to delete the session by parsing into every users session data and retrieve session's last access time and then delete it, if it is not accessed for more than an hour. Its moreover an hack. Is there any clean way of doing that?
If there is anything in mysql like automatic deletion of sessions when it get expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sessions table, you could store a DATETIME field representing the last access time of the session. Obviously, you could update this field each time the user accesses a resource using their session.

It would then be possible to run a Perl script on a cron which deletes all sessions older than one hour.

Example:

```
delete from SESSIONS where access_time < DATE_SUB(now(),interval 1 hour)
```

This will delete all records from the `SESSIONS` table where the `access_time` timestamp is older than one hour. Any sessions that have been accessed within the last hour will not be deleted.

Comment: could u please explain the query a bit

Comment: if u could please tell me how to include another column in sessions table.

Comment: That is another question in its own right, but look up the syntax for alter table - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: No i am asking about sessions in perl CGI::sessions not about mysql.. Anyway thanks for your help